# spring boot in docker container not reacting to connection

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, docker, tomcat

So I have been trying now for a long time to get this work. The problem is I am starting a spring boot application in a docker container, but for some odd reason, I cannot connect to it. When I start the container in the logs it tells that the tomcat server is serving on the port 8080:
[image: image of the logs]

I started the image with the command:

```
sudo docker run -p 8080:8080 --name rest restcon
```

QA:

trying to connecting to it means trying in postman to connect to a rest endpoint which worked fine on the localhost, but on the server in a container doesn't.

Comment: When you say you "can't connect to it" how exactly are you trying? And what is the exact result?

Answer (score 0):

Are you certain the Springboot application is running correctly in the container ? `sudo docker exec -it rest bash` will let you access the container, from there you can check if the application is running and is indeed accessible on 8080.